# How do I eliminate stubborn white space between fluidRows in Shiny?

Tags: html, css, r, shiny, whitespace

I have two fluidRows in a column of my UI in Shiny.

I want the top row to have a slight space above it, but **I want to eliminate any space between the rows**.

- I've tried `div`, `tags`, and an assortment of style arguments like `margin: 0px` and `padding: 0px ...`, but I can't get the spacing to act accordingly.

  - Here's an example:

    ```
    ui <- fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
    column(1,offset=0,
           div(style = "font-size: 10px; padding: 14px 0px; margin:0%",
               fluidRow(
                 sliderInput(inputId = "sizeSlide", label = "Sizing", value = 10, min = 1,max = 20)
               )
           ),
           div(style = "font-size: 10px; padding: 0px 0px; margin:0px", 
               fluidRow(
                 radioButtons(inputId = "greatORless", label = "DBH Limiter", choices = c(">", "<"), selected = ">")
               )                                      
           )
        )
      )
    )
    ```

What I get is this:

[image]   <sup>(Notice the large [unwanted] space between rows)</sup>

What I want is this:

[image]   <sup>(Notice the significantly smaller space between rows)</sup>

How do I do this??

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use negative values on `margin`, in this case use `margin-top:-2em` to affect only the top margin. I prefer to use relative units, but you can use pixel instead of `em`.

```R
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
fluidRow(
column(1, offset = 0,
       div(style = "font-size: 10px;
                   padding: 14px 0px;
                   margin:0%",
           fluidRow(
             sliderInput(inputId = "sizeSlide",
                         label = "Sizing",
                         value = 10,
                         min = 1,
                         max = 20)
           )
       ),
       div(style = "font-size: 10px;
                   padding: 0px 0px;
                   margin-top:-2em", 
           fluidRow(
             radioButtons(inputId = "greatORless",
                          label = "DBH Limiter",
                          choices = c(">", "<"),
                          selected = ">")
           )                                      
       )
    )
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Works! Thanks :)

Comment: This works when I run the app in RStudio, but not when I open it in a browser (Chrome). Any ideas?

Comment: doesn't work.
Error in .Primitive("/")(dots[[1L]][[1L]], dots[[2L]][[1L]]) : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator